# Move from IReactiveDerivedList to DynamicData

Tags: dynamic-data, reactiveui

Has simple code in old version of ReactiveUI:

```
var allItems = new ObservableCollection<Model>(items);
var filteredItems = allItems.CreateDerivedCollection(
 x => x,
 Filter,
 Comparer.Compare);
```

where `Filter` and `Compare` has simple signatures:

```
private bool Filter(Model item)
public int Compare(Model x, Model y)
```

sometimes i change items in other threads (big changes, without INPC) or change Filter\Compare strategies and just do `filteredItems.Reset();`

---

In DynamicData i try to:

```
          ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Model> filteredItems;
          var allItems = new ObservableCollection<Model>(items);
          var cancellation = allItems
            .ToObservableChangeSet()
            .Filter(Filter)
            .Sort(Comparer)
            .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
            .Bind(out filteredItems)
            .DisposeMany()
            .Subscribe();
```

but not found, how to `Reset` this^ or `filteredItems`.

Comment: There is a operator called "AutoRefreshOnObservable()" I have used for this purpose in the past. I will pass in an Observable to the method (it has one parameter which is for each item in the list which I ignore), and then I just trigger the observables to get a full reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wish I were able to give you a direct answer, but I'm rather new to ReactiveUI. Managed to use DynamicData for something and thought you wouldn't mind this sharing.

If what I say later doesn't help you, here are the most relevant resources I could find:

- https://floatingcube.com/blog/convert-reactive-list-to-dynamic-data/
- https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData/wiki/Introduction-for-ReactiveUI-users
- https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData/issues/182
- https://habr.com/en/post/454074/

---

In my case I used `SourceList` or `SourceCache` as type for something similar to your `allItems`.

```
SourceCache<Model, string> allItems =
    new SourceCache<Model, string>(m => m.Id);

// assuming each model has unique id; if it doesn't then use SourceList
```

I'd then have a `BindingList<Model>` as type for something simlar to your 'filteredItems'.

```
BindingList<Model> filteredItems = new BindingList<Model>();
```

The binding should be something like:

```
allItems
    .Connect()
    ...
    .ObserveOn(...)
    .Bind(filteredItems)
    .Subscribe();
```

To bulk-edit the list I'd call something like

```
allItems.Edit(
    innerList => {
    innerList.Clear();

    // edit
    // innerList.AddOrUpdate(...);
});
```

---

Cheers !

Comment: IBindingList not work for me, but code work well with ReadOnlyObservableCollection. Thanks.